# How Facebook image uploading by clicking on "Take a picture" works in mobile?

Tags: php, iphone, cordova, sencha-touch, image-uploading

In my PHP website I want to implement image uploading functionality. So,when I browse or surf Facebook in my mobile browser (iPhone, Android, Symbian OS) I am able to take a picture from my mobile camera and able to upload. I want to use the same functionality in my website but don't know how to do it, or how it works.

For that I searched a lot and found so many results that the idea of "PhoneGap" is useful.

How can I integrate image uploading functionality? When I click on "Take a picture", my mobile's camera should turn on automatically, capture the image and upload it to my website.

Answer (score 1):

Website can't access the image in the image library on iOS. You can;t even upload a file since the file system in accessible.

What tool like phone gap do translate javascript call to native call, but you can only do this  in native apps (meaning sending it in the the app store).

Comment: Yes,i made website development for Iphone n Ipad ,when any user surf my website in iphone and ipad, a differeny version i made,n it will be used, and if we browse facebook.com in our mobile's browser,for that we are able to take a picture through mobile's camera n upload it,i want to use the same functionality....

Comment: You can't upload images in the facebook mobile website, only the app can do that.

Comment: Yes,i got it,but is that possible ? or any alternate way to do with website??

Comment: Which part of "you can't upload images" don't you understand! Mobile website on iOS can't access images. Only nativ apps can access images. You could allow your use to mail the images and use separate email accounts for each user. Just like facebook.

Comment: Can you give me any example regarding this?

Comment: What kind of example do you wan't? Just go to the facebook mobile site it will tell you to send an email.